# What books would you recommend to understand mathematically the Dirac matter

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am a math student who got interested in the topics above also i want to learn about the Dirac matter the spinors the Einsteins GR and the Yang-Mills Maxwell Anderson Higgs theories and models and general gauge theories and wants to understand them. What are some good introductory books for people like me where they have some mathematical understanding but not physics background. I need this books to describe these mathematical and not just explain them in general.

Comment: Most textbooks on GR have a few sections devoted to spinors in GR (off the top of my head, both Wald and Misner do a good job and also contain the essential physics from a not-too-advanced starting point). Which have you tried so far? You'd probably be better off getting a textbook devoted to just GR first to do it justice.

Comment: Also a book called the geometry of physics by Frankel contains a lot about GR, gauge theory, Yang-Mills, spinors, etc, from a more mathematical perspective (although not much cross over between them).